# What am I sealing as I install my Shower Faucet Stem and Handle?

Tags: shower, faucet, seal

As a result of a leak, I replaced my shower's hot water faucet stem. ([I think](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/141684/86552)) I installed it successfully, but now I am wondering which hole I am trying to seal.
[image: Faucet stem without handle]

Am I trying to seal the entire hole around the stem or seal the edge of the sleeve that I will seat around the stem (see the metal sleeve at the base of the other handle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way would be if you put a bead of plumbers putty on the back of the sleeve, it's easier now and latter on if you have to remove it again.